# The first Image of each row not resizing in TYPO3 "Image" or "Image w/ Text" Element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I've already discovered that issue in a TYPO3 6.2.x Version and now having the same problem in TYPO 7.6.x.

It's always the first image of a row not resizing, no matter how images added to an element or how many rows configured. TYPO3 is somehow obviously trying to do something with the image, as the source is "/fileadmin/*processed*/.." - but the image size is the original size. All other images in the row have the wanted and configured size.

I've found a 3 year old entry in the TYPO3 Board with the same problem, but no solution: https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/195320/content-type-quot-images-quot-erstes-bild-wird-nicht-verkleinert
So it looks like i am not paranoid at all. : )

Anyone else discovered that issue? Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me it was a calculation bug in `/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/Classes/Controller/CssStyledContentController.php:578` (TYPO3 7.6.10):

```
$netW = $maxW - $colspacing * ($colCount - 1) - $colCount * $border * ($borderThickness + $borderSpace) * 2;
```

Without modifying the core, I was able to solve it by setting

```
tt_content.image.20.colSpace = 0
tt_content.textpic.20.colSpace = 0
```

So the calculation doesn’t return a negative integer for the first image in a row, which has negative impact in further processing of the image, ultimately resulting in not scaling/cropping the image.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me a lot (in TYPO3 8.7.x)!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information:
Which content element are you using: textpic/images or textmedia?

How is tab "appearance" configured?

Are there modifiactions in tt_content f.i. due to bootstrap package or s.e.?

Comment: Hello Stefan, thank's for following up. As mentioned in the title the "error" is happening with “Image” or “Image w/ Text” Elements. No special configuration or plugins at all. tab "Appearance" is default.